# How to create a function to print a word going in different directions (vertically, diagonally)

Tags: python

I'm looking to create a function that takes a word and print it in a specified direction:
when `n = 0`, print vertically, when `n = 1` print diagonally.

```
def word_direction(text, direction=n):
    print(word)
```

Comment: What do you mean by direction, and especially what do you mean by diagonally. Please give an example ouput.

Comment: Please first show us what you have tried already. We are here to help you solve problems, not give you full solution.

Comment: I would advise you to try with different things until you get to the output you are expecting. Remember that in python you can iterate through strings with a for loop. `for letter in word: ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use if statments to check what the direction is then write code to print the text in that direction

```
def word_direction(text,direction):
  if direction==0:
    for char in text:
      print(char)
  elif direction==1:
    for spaces,value in enumerate(text):
      print(" "*spaces,value)
  elif direction==2:
    print(text)
  elif direction==3:
    for pos,value in enumerate(text[::-1]):
      spaces=len(text)-pos-1
      print(" "*spaces,value)
```

Comment: this doesnt work, `" "*char` char is a `str` here

Comment: Using the `enumerate` function to get the index of each character in the string would be more pythonic than using `range` and then indexing in to the string.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach, which uses `enumerate()` to get the index for each character of the text and then to create a string with a number of spaces equal to the index of the character in text to create the diagonal effect. After the spaces the character itself is concatenated, and finally the string is printed.

When `direction = 0` this operation is short-circuited and only char is printed.
By default `print()` prints a newline character at then end, which is useful for both modes.

```
def word_direction(text, direction = 1):
    for i, char in enumerate(text):
        print(''.join((' ' * i * direction, char)))
        
word_direction('Hello World!', direction = 0) # Prints vertically
word_direction('Hello World!', direction = 1) # Prints diagonally
```

Output (`direction = 0`):

```
H
 e
  l
   l
    o
      
      W
       o
        r
         l
          d
           !
```

Output (`direction = 1`):

```
H
e
l
l
o
 
W
o
r
l
d
!
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you:

```
def word_direction(text, direction):
    if direction==0:
        for ch in text:
            print(ch)
    elif direction==1:
        for i in range(len(text)):
            print(' '*i,text[i])

word_direction('Hello World!',0)  #prints vertically
word_direction('Hello World!',1)  #prints diagonally
```